# get socket.io option's query in nodejs

Tags: java, android, node.js

I created a chat application with android java as client and node.js as server side.

**Client side:**

```
IO.Options opt=new IO.Options();
opt.query="token=anything";
socket = IO.socket("http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:PORT",opt);
socket.connect();
```

i want to send a token on connection and get it in server for validation...
how can i get the token that i pushed in opt.query in node.js?

And if you have good idea for sending some data like tokens on connection or somework for secure the connection Please note that.

**Thank you**

**Solution**
server side:

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
console.log(socket.handshake.query.token);
});
```

thanks for @Marcos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the query options in Node.js via `socket.handshake.query`

```
const ws = io(http);

ws.use(async(socket, next) => {

    try {
        await validateToken(socket.handshake.query.token));
        return next();
    } catch(e) {
        return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }

});

ws.on('connection', socket => {
      /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Thank's @Marcos socket.handshake.query.token is solved my problem.  do you have any idea for securing the connection? please introduce a source

Comment: Use SSL. wss protocol.